# Have to make a connection string for my C# Application with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, connection

I have problem with my C# application with database connection on the client PC.

I have developed an application for a small store which controlling from one computer my means it's not over LAN or WAN, it is just one computer database for my friend's shop.

Now the problem is that the system is working fine in my PC but the connection is not working on my friend's PC.

My connection string is:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Store");
```

If there is any way to solve this problem?

Are there any great tutorials to learn all C# and ASP.net? Thanks Dears.

Comment: Open up SQL Server Management Studio which comes with SQL Server.  The login screen has an instance name of the database.  Replace the period in the connection string with the instance name in the login screen.

Comment: Is your software running somewhere else & Database is somewhere else ?
If Yes. then make sure your pc can reach the dtabase PC. 
you can check with http://helpmepal.org as they can connect to team viewer & try to solve your problem

Comment: Show us how you know it's not working. Are you getting an error message? More information helps us help you.

Comment: *Are there any great tutorials to learn all c# and ASP.net? Thanks Dears.* - this portion of your question is off-topic for stack overflow, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic which states *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.  Also, please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

Answer (score 0):

```
        string databaseservername = "yourdatabaseservername";
        string DatabaseName = "yoursdatabase";

        string loginid = "yourdatabaseuserid";
        string Password = "yourdatabasepassword";
        string connectionString = "Data Source=" + databaseservername + ";Initial 
        Catalog=" + DatabaseName + ";User ID=" + loginid + ";pwd=" + Password + ";";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Comment: Thanks you dear friends. Your's answers have solved my problem.